# Sort X axis in google charts by month names

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I want to sort the month names on the X axis using google charts. I currently use `dataGroup.sort([{column: 0}]);` to sort alphabetically. How do i sort the values w.r.t the month?

[image]

```
var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
            sliderData,
            [0, 2],
            [{column: 1, aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum, type: 'number', label: 'Count'}]
        );
```

dataGroup now has data something like-

```
    gvjs_K {Sp: null, cf: Array(3), Vf: Array(34), qr: null, cache: Array(0), …}
Sp: null
Vf: Array(34)
0:
c: Array(3)
0: {v: "August"}
1: {v: "Adult Player"}
2: {v: 13307}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
1:
c: Array(3)
0: {v: "August"}
1: {v: "Coach"}
2: {v: 4062}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
2: {c: Array(3)}
3: {c: Array(3)}
```

Comment: Can you post your data sample (JSON) here?

Comment: and any relevant code...

Comment: Updated. @WhiteHat I am using this datagroup and chart reference from your previous answers in a different post. :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `DataView` class and the `setRows` method to set a custom sort order.
the `setRows` method works by providing an array of row indexes in the order the rows should appear.

in this example, we use an array of month names to determine the correct order.
then we sort the row indexes accordingly, and use `setRows` to build the data table.

**1.** create an array with the month names in the correct order

```
var monthOrder = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December'
];
```

**2.** use the `getSortedRows` method to get an array of the row indexes from the data table

```
var rows = data.getSortedRows([{column: 0}]);
```

**3.** sort the array of row indexes using the name index from the month names array

```
rows.sort(function (a, b) {
  var monthA = data.getValue(a, 0);
  var monthB = data.getValue(b, 0);
  return monthOrder.indexOf(monthA) - monthOrder.indexOf(monthB);
});
```

**4.** create a data view and use the `setRows` method to set the custom sort

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setRows(rows);
```

then use the data view to draw the chart

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['April',  2000.9, 1215.3],
    ['August',   300.5,   2512],
    ['December',  600.3, 7518.6],
    ['February',   2500.4,  8852.7],
    ['January',  1453.5,  5005.7],
    ['June',  4300.5,  9635.7],
    ['July',   2588.4,  7418.7],
    ['March',   3588.5,   1221],
    ['May',  1666.3, 8518.6],
    ['November',  2446.3, 6218.6],
    ['October',  8556.3, 4218.6],
    ['September',  1222.9, 1415.3]
  ], true);

  var chartRaw = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_raw'));
  chartRaw.draw(data);

  // sort rows by month name chronologically
  var monthOrder = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
  ];
  var rows = data.getSortedRows([{column: 0}]);
  rows.sort(function (a, b) {
    var monthA = data.getValue(a, 0);
    var monthB = data.getValue(b, 0);
    return monthOrder.indexOf(monthA) - monthOrder.indexOf(monthB);
  });
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setRows(rows);

  var chartSort = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_sort'));
  chartSort.draw(view);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>not sorted</div>
<div id="chart_div_raw"></div>
<div>sorted</div>
<div id="chart_div_sort"></div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. It didn't at the beginning but noticed the spelling of 'February'. :P. Thanks @WhiteHat